# TFS and powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem

I am able to create my tasks [using the script here](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/automating-task-creation-in-team-foundation-server-with-powershell/).

My question how I can tell Powershell to link those created task to go under specific user story. For example I created Task# 2000 which is "Regression testing" to under user story 1950. How I link between them? Appreciate any help.

Comment: BTW, I am not a developer. I am just trying to create this query so that I can automate creating my task quickly, this will save me few hours every sprint.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really simplified code just to get you started on linking workitems.

(just make sure the TeamFoundation dlls exist in this path or change it)

```
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"

    $type = "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore" -as [type]

    // Create the TF
    $tfs = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServer("http://server/tfs/collection")
    $store = $tfs.GetService($type)


    $project = $store.Projects["WITLab"] // select the Teamproject
    $parentWorkitem =  $project.Store.GetWorkItem(53) // get the parent workitem by ID
    $rl = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.RelatedLink(40) // create related link with the child ID 

    //Add the link and save the Workitem
    $Parentwit.Links.Add($rl)
    $Parentwit.Save()
```

Comment: If you want it to be a Parent/Child link you need to use the `Link` class, instead of the `RelatedLink` class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemlink.aspx